# Use values from output in different worksheets for a calculated field in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I have two worksheets, each with the same variable but with different filters working on that variable in each worksheet.

For example:

In worksheet 1: [Run/100] = 2.1

In worksheet 2, with filters applied: [Run/100] = 4.0

What I would like to do is create a calculated field that takes the current value of [Run/100] in worksheet 1 and divides it by the current value of [Run/100] in worksheet 2. I have searched around, but can't seem to find anything on referencing worksheet values in Tableau.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: You won't find any reference like that, basically because it's not how Tableau works. You need to understand how to perform your calculation using your database alone. If it's just matter of filters, you can use IF or CASE statements.

Comment: Thanks. The issue is I want the new calculated field to update dynamically based on what the user selects from the filters. As a result I can't "hard code" specific filter values into the calculation.

Comment: I see. Ideally you would have 2 "filters", where the user would select the values, and you could make the calculation based on that. Unfortunately Tableau does not have this feature. A filter will, well, filter the entries. It won't create 2 subsets and work with those on the same worksheet. You could still work with parameters, but not very likely to find a good solution